# How can I make a program to run as service in Linux

Tags: linux, tomcat

Thanks for looking into my question.

I am running tomcat as windows service in windows machine. how can I achieve the same on linux machines.

it should start automatically after reboot.

Thanks,
R Dama.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install Tomcat from a Linux distribution package, it will usually include an init script which will start it as a daemon via a start stop script. You can create a script for it manually otherwise. See https://www.linux.com/learn/managing-linux-daemons-init-scripts

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. I will try this.